# Discarding DLL's resource after using it

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll, portable-executable

I'm creating a dll with an embedded binary resource. Currently when I load this DLL it gets memory mapped into my process address space. The problem is that the embedded binary resource is huge and I don't want to keep it around once I'm done using it.

I tried looking up documentation regarding this and apparently there are sections in the PE file which don't get memory mapped(relocation section). Also, I can create new sections and flag it IMAGE_SCN_MEM_DISCARDABLE but this flag is ignored outside of kernel mode.

There was a win API function which supported freeing resources for 16-bit Windows but doesn't work 32-bit onward. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648044%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says "This function is obsolete and is only supported for backward compatibility with 16-bit Windows. For 32-bit Windows applications, it is not necessary to free the resources loaded using LoadResource. If used on 32 or 64-bit Windows systems, this function will return FALSE". I don't know what they mean by that but it seems like they don't expect resources to be huge and can be accommodated in the address space.

Is there any way for me to keep discard the resources I load after I'm done using them?

Comment: The .rsrc section of an executable is already discardable.  There is no point whatsoever in helping, unless you need the address space for some reason.  In itself a rapidly disappearing problem, 64-bit operating systems are getting to be universal.  Which you do by putting the resources in another DLL so you can unload it explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system will discard them if it needs to. So long as you are not referring to the memory, it can be discarded and paged out if the system needs the physical memory for something else. So, it won't stop physical memory being used for that which needs it.

That said, linked resources are not intended to be huge. The point is that a module is mapped into a contiguous range of memory. If your module is really huge then it may be impossible to find such a contiguous range of memory. What's more, the module's address range is reserved for the entire lifetime of the resource. That means that nothing else in the process can use that virtual memory address range. So even if a contiguous address range can be found, it is forever reserved for the module and that address range cannot be used for anything else. And this can easily become a problem for 32 bit applications.

So, by putting the huge resource in memory you won't incur a long-standing drain on physical resources, but you will put an unavoidable constraint on virtual memory address space resources.

The conclusion to draw is that such huge objects should be held in external files and not linked to the module as a resource. If you absolutely must use a resource in a PE module, then put the resource into a separate DLL. Load the DLL with `LoadLibrary`, pull out the resource using the module handle you got from `LoadLibrary`, and then unload the DLL with `FreeLibrary`.

Comment: Thanks David! I agree that having them as an external file is the best solution but, our application can build DLLs and we zip and add multiple binary files as resource and at times then number of files can grow to a large number. The DLL is used by our customer and they tend to copy it to different locations and don't want them to have to copy another file. The solution we were looking for is to have to copy around a single file but be able to treat it as individual files while loading. Is there a way we can add a big file to a DLL and not have it memory mapped when the DLL gets loaded?

Comment: No there is no such way to partially unmap a DLL. The only way is to use an external file, or an separate DLL which can then be unloaded with a call to `FreeLibrary`.

Comment: Perhaps he could launch a subprocess whose only job is to load the DLL (and hence can be simple enough that reserving the contiguous memory shouldn't be a problem) and then copy just the data he actually needs across the process boundary?